# AlarmManager never fires

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I have made an alarm manager... I used it once and it worked flawless, now it won't work at all.

Here is my code:

**OnBootReceiver.java**

```
package com.example.gpstracking;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.SystemClock;

public class OnBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  private static final int PERIOD=300000;  // 5 minutes

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AlarmManager mgr=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i=new Intent(context, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
                                              i, 0);

    mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                      SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+60000,
                      PERIOD,
                      pi);
  }
}
```

**AppService.java**

```
package com.example.gpstracking;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class AppService extends WakefulIntentService {
    GPSTracker gps;

    public AppService() {
        super("AppService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doWakefulWork(Intent intent) {
        gps = new GPSTracker(AppService.this);

        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

            double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
            SendLocation SendLocation = new SendLocation();
            SendLocation.execute(latitude, longitude);
            Log.i("Info:","Got here");

        } else {
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }
    }
}
```

**OnAlarmReceiver.java**

```
package com.example.gpstracking;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class OnAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    WakefulIntentService.acquireStaticLock(context);

    context.startService(new Intent(context, AppService.class));
  }
}
```

**WakefulIntentService.java**

```
package com.example.gpstracking;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.PowerManager;

abstract public class WakefulIntentService extends IntentService {
  abstract void doWakefulWork(Intent intent);

  public static final String LOCK_NAME_STATIC="com.example.gpstracking.AppService.Static";
  private static PowerManager.WakeLock lockStatic=null;

  public static void acquireStaticLock(Context context) {
    getLock(context).acquire();
  }

  synchronized private static PowerManager.WakeLock getLock(Context context) {
    if (lockStatic==null) {
      PowerManager mgr=(PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

      lockStatic=mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                            LOCK_NAME_STATIC);
      lockStatic.setReferenceCounted(true);
    }

    return(lockStatic);
  }

  public WakefulIntentService(String name) {
    super(name);
  }

  @Override
  final protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    try {
      doWakefulWork(intent);
    }
    finally {
      getLock(this).release();
    }
  }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.gpstracking"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".AndroidGPSTrackingActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".OnBootReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".OnAlarmReceiver" >
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".AppService" >
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have played with it for hours with no luck at all. I'm hoping somebody else has an idea.

Comment: Well, I would recommend using [a correct implementation of my `WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful). Beyond that, you can use **`adb shell dumpsys alarm`** to see if your alarms are scheduled. Also note that if you are running on Android 4.4+, and your `android:targetSdkVersion` is 19 or higher, your repeating alarms are now inexact.

Comment: Try logging something to console in your receivers and service just to  understand what methods are invoked. Are `OnBootReceiver.onReceive`, `OnAlarmReceiver.onReceive`, `AppService.doWakefulWork` invoked?